# blazor add parameters to templated component

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have a Blazor Popup that takes a template to show his content:

*CustomPopup.razor*

```
<Popup
    @bind-Visible="@CreatePopupVisible"
    HorizontalAlignment="HorizontalAlignment.Center"
    VerticalAlignment="VerticalAlignment.Center"
    ShowFooter="true"
    HeaderText="@("Create" + Label)">
    <BodyTemplate>
        @EditForm
    </BodyTemplate>
    <FooterContentTemplate>
    </FooterContentTemplate>
</Popup>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Label { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment EditForm { get; set; }

    bool CreatePopupVisible { get; set; }

}
```

to this component i pass an EditForm with 2 buttons that takes a function to handle the cancel option:

*CustomEditForm.razor*

```
<EditForm Model="Entity" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <InputNumber id="factory-id" class="mt-2 mb-2" @bind-Value="Entity.Id" />
        <InputText id="factory-businessname" class="mt-2 mb-2" @bind-Value="Entity.BusinessName" />
        <InputText id="factory-address" class="mt-2 mb-2" @bind-Value="Entity.Address" />
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <button class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mb-2 flex-grow-1" type="submit">Modifica</button>
            <button @onclick="HandleCancel" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2 mb-2 flex-grow-1" type="submit">Annulla</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public Action HandleCancel { get; set; }
    

    [Parameter]
    public Factory Entity { get; set; }
    
    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("HandleValidSubmit called");
    }
}
```

if i use the EditForm normally like this:

*SomeFile.razor*

```
<CustomEditForm HandleCancel="()=>{}">
```

its all good but when i use it in a templated component how can i pass a function to him from inside the CustomPupup.razor file?

i need to pass a function to set CreatePopupVisible to false when someone clicks on the cancel button

ty in advance for the help!

## EDIT

ty for the help but i think i provided not enough information to get the right answer, my bad

so, i want to be able to call the CustomEditForm normally and passing a function defined by the parent to manage the HandleCancel like this:

*MainPage.razor*

```
@page ...

<Grid @ref="Grid">
//the grid has a method that closes this CustomEditForm
    <Template>
        <CustomEditForm HandleCancel="() => Grid.CancelRowEdit()"/>
    </Template>
</Grid>
```

but i also want to close the popup using a function defined inside himself like this:

AnotherPage.razor

```
<CustomPopup>
    <EditForm>
        <CustomEditForm Entity="new Factory()"/>
    </EditForm>
</CustomPopup>
```

in this case the edit form should handle the cancel by calling a CustomPopup defined method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to pass a reference to an internal method to the `RenderFragment`, which you can do with `RenderFragment<Action>` - as `HandleCancel` expects an `Action` it can `invoke`:

```html
<Popup
    @bind-Visible="@CreatePopupVisible"
    HorizontalAlignment="HorizontalAlignment.Center"
    VerticalAlignment="VerticalAlignment.Center"
    ShowFooter="true"
    HeaderText="@("Create" + Label)">
    <BodyTemplate>
        @EditForm(ClosePopup)
    </BodyTemplate>
    <FooterContentTemplate>
    </FooterContentTemplate>
</Popup>
```

```cs
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Label { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<Action> EditForm { get; set; }

    bool CreatePopupVisible { get; set; }

    void ClosePopup() 
    {
        CreatePopupVisible = false;

        // Because this method will be called by some external code
        // You should tell this component to render:

        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    } 
}
```

To use this, the markup can reference the `context` of the `EditForm` `RenderFragment`, which is an `Action`

```html
<CustomPopup>
    <EditForm>
        <CustomEditForm Entity="new Factory()" HandleCancel=@context/>
    </EditForm>
</CustomPopup>
```

[Try it out](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/cGkcavYb51ZqIrBN58)

Comment: this is perfect ty so much!

Answer (score 0):

As there's isn't quite enough code in your question to use as the basis for an answer, I'll use a very simple component to demonstrate how you can do what you want.

Here's my "PopUp" emulator.

```
@if (this.Visible)
{
    <h3>PopUp</h3>
    @this.ChildContent
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool Visible { get; set; }
}
```

And then my CustomPopUp.  Note I'm cacading `this` and have a public `Close` method.

```
<PopUp Visible="this.CreatePopupVisible">
    <CascadingValue Value=this>
    @this.ChildContent
    </CascadingValue>
</PopUp>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    bool CreatePopupVisible { get; set; }

    public void Show()
    {
        this.CreatePopupVisible = true;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        this.CreatePopupVisible = false;
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Next my EditForm.  Note that I capture the Cascaded instance of `CustomMyPopUp`.  My Cancel now checks if we have a cascaded value (We're in a PopUp context) and if so calls `Close` on the popup.  It also checks if there's a registerted delegate on `HandleCancel` and only invokes it if there is one.

```
<div class="m-2 p-5 bg-light">
<h3>EditForm</h3>
<div class="p-2 m-2">
<button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="this.Cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private CustomPopUp? myPopUp { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> HandleCancel { get; set; }

    public async Task Cancel()
    {
        if (this.myPopUp is not null)
            myPopUp.Close();
        if (this.HandleCancel.HasDelegate)
            await HandleCancel.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

Finally my page to test it:

```
@page "/PopUp"
<h3>CascadePage</h3>
<CustomPopUp @ref=this.myPopUp>
    <MyEditForm />
</CustomPopUp>

<div class="p-2 m-2">
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.Show">Show</button>
</div>

@code {
    private CustomPopUp? myPopUp;

    public void Show()
    => this.myPopUp?.Show();
}
```

Comment: im updating the question to have more details, ty for the help

Comment: So, If I read this correctly you want to be able to close the PopUp box containing the editor from both inside the EditForm with a `Cancel` button, and from within the parent `Grid` form by clicking a `CancelEdit`  control of some type from within the row?

Comment: the CustomEditForm has a button labelled close, when pressed it calls a function passed as a property, the CustomEditForm can be placed both on his own next to a grid so when the close on the edit form is clicked the grid do something, but it also need to be able to be passed as a RenderFragment to a CustomPopup, the problem is the method to close the CustomPopup is declared in CustomPopup where the Renderfragment is appended so i cant pass a parameter to it

Comment: basically i want to be able to pass a function directly to the component and to the component given as a renderfragment, the only problem is that the code to close the popup is in the same file as the append of the renderfragment so i cant use the regular <> markup i append it with @EditForm but now i cant pass parameters

Comment: [Polite]  I think you need to reconsider your design.  To achieve what you envisage I think you need a service that the component, form and page communicate through.  You also need to stop thinking of passing the form as a `RenderFragment` and think of passing is as a `Type`.  However fundamentally I think you are overcomplicating the design.  Can't you use a normal modal dialog, such as  BLAZORED - https://github.com/Blazored/Modal or a more simple one I wrote here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5286721/A-Simple-Bootstrap-Modal-Dialog-for-Blazor

Comment: yeah i might have slightly overcomplicated it, ill refactor it in the future, ty for the advice :D

Comment: No problem.  I see Mister Magoo got you an answer ;-)